# How to print different types of Json data returned by my service?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I cannot figure out how to correctly print the data returned from my service, CompanyProvider.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CompanyProvider} from "../../../providers/company/company";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-settings-company',
  templateUrl: 'settings-company.html',
})
export class SettingsCompanyPage {

  companyInfo:any;
  jobs: any;
  maquinaria:any;
  otrosDocumentos:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public _cp: CompanyProvider) {
    console.log("You're in settingsCompany");
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    console.log("CRETE FORM");

    let idCompany = this.navParams.get('id');
    console.log("ID DE Compañia desde Settings-company : " + idCompany);

    //get CompanyInfo  


    this._cp.getCompanyInfo(idCompany).then(
      companyInfo=>this.companyInfo=companyInfo
    )
    //get Jobs

    this._cp.getJobs(idCompany).then(data => {
      this.jobs  = data;}
    )

   //get maquinaria
    this._cp.getMaquinaria(idCompany).then(data => {
      this.maquinaria = data;}
    )

    //get otros_dcoumentos
    this._cp.getOtrosDocumentos(idCompany).then(data => {
      this.otrosDocumentos = data;}
    )
  }

}
```

I dont know if I need to proccess the data before passing it to local variables used to print in view.

I use the following in my view:

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <h4>{{companyInfo|json}}</h4>
  <h4>{{jobs | json}}</h4>

</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and the result is:

[image]

I've tried the following but this doesn't return anything, and the console tells me that it is undefined. In the second Json, I dont know how can i loop occupations to show with ngfor.

```
<h4>{{companyInfo.name}}</h4>
```

Comment: You need to render companyInfo in html..

Comment: i already give you a answer please give me feedback is it work or not...

Answer (score 0):

**Render `companyInfo` in `.html`, i show `name` in `ion-item`**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list> 
     <ion-item *ngFor="let eachItem of companyInfo"
        <h4>{{eachItem.name}}</h4>
     </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this type example :-

```
<div *ngIf="companyInfo && companyInfo.length">
<div *ngFor="let company of companyInfo">
<h4>{{company.name}}</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , and how can i loop occupations of the second json ?

Comment: its simple wait i am describe now

Comment: thank you this lines work fine  , so i am trying to loop occupations of second JSON with this   <div *ngFor="let job of jobs.occupations">
<h4>{{job.id}}</h4>
</div>   but this doesnt function , the error : Cannot read property 'occupations' of undefined  , how can i loop this , please

Comment: jobs.occupations its wrong please use only var whose store your job value.